# DokuWiki server-side caching

Tags: php, apache, caching, amazon-elb, dokuwiki

I've got a DokuWiki site with a lot of pages with Apache 2.4 as a Web server behind ELB instance. The ELB health check runs on test.html page.

I've got a call to Doku.php from two different IP addresses (which seems to be related ELB instance), and then it seems that they try to access all of the website, for example, these are from the Apache logs:

172.31.50.143 - - [24/Oct/2015:22:01:15 +0000] "GET /dokuwiki/doku.php?id=profile_flynnbackhaus HTTP/1.1" 200 2994

172.31.57.162 - - [24/Oct/2015:22:01:15 +0000] "GET /dokuwiki/doku.php?id=profile_merrinall4982 HTTP/1.1" 200 2311

After a while, the Apache server runs out of memory, and restarts itself, but it happens very frequently.

My questions are:

1. Is there a server-side built-in caching mechanism to configure or in code in DokuWiki? If so, how can I disable it? Maybe this question is more related to Apache server... I'm not sure.
2. How can I handle these kinds of issues programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like you have some kind of memory leak problem. There are tonns of similar issues discussed, see, fo example - https://serverfault.com/questions/88997/how-can-i-determine-the-cause-of-an-areqest,t-memory-leak-in-my-apache-php-based-w

There is no silver bullet for this type of issue, so in general you have to debug your app carefully - find out, which requsts increase apache memory use faster, look into the code, may be try to analise process memory etc...

If you are NOT expecting to have high loads on your site, you may deside to reconfigure youf app to run as cgi application - than, OS will free memory for you, but in expense of doing it after EVERY reqest. So, when you will have, say, 100 concurrent users, you may get into trouble ;)

Comment: Firstly, I'll mark this as answer once I'll find what's causing the leak using the link you've provided and the DokuWiki code. I know for sure that there's over 1.6GB worth of articles which are being indexed right after starting up the web server. Secondly, and as an immediate step (as recommended here), I've deployed the site in IIS using FastCGI and memory issues were resolved, but I had to increase timeout from 90 sec to 600 sec, since the request to Site Index plugin takes about 3.5 min and after a while gets to 7 minutes. Serious issue with user experience. /now, to analyze... :-)

Comment: Site index plugin in 3.5 min. Hmm. Is it reindexing all the pages to create some fast-searching (in-memory?) tables? If so, may be moving such a tables onto, say, SSD-backed storage will make it possible to create index only once and just update it as necessary?